# Filter EntityType by owner/current user

Tags: php, symfony

I have an EntityType field in a form:

```
$builder->add('site')
```

now all the sites are shown in the dropdown, but I want to show only the ones that belong to the current user.

The app logic is that there are many users, each of them can manage only their own sites (Site::user is a `@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="sites")`)

I know I can use the `query_builder` - but what is the best way to get the current user inside the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the current user object (or id) in the form there are actually multiple ways. One would be to set it via the form's options

```
$form = $this->createForm(MyFormType::class, $obj, [
    'user' => $this->getUser(),
]);
```

And enable the option with default value `null` like so.

```
class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
            $resolver->setDefaults([
                    'data_class' => '...',
                    'user' => null,
            ]);
    }
```

Now you can use `$options['user']` within the `buildForm()` (make sure to check if it is `null` or not before using).

---

But this way you have to always inject the user yourself - why not let Symfony take care of it? First, register your form as a service in services.yml like so

```
app.form.myform:
    class: AppBundle\Form\MyFormType
    arguments: ["@security.token_storage"]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type }
```

You see, I already added another thing: the `@security.token_storage` argument. Now in your form, add a constructor

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{

    protected $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
            $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }
```

And retrieving the user within `buildForm()` will now be as easy as

```
$user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
```

Comment: Thank you. With the first solution, I got `The option "user" does not exist.`. I've added user as a property of $obj (`$obj->user = $this->getUser()` before calling createForm)

Comment: @the_nuts I have updated my answer, of course you need to enable the option to be able to use it.